# Use datetime with different timezones (discord.py)

Tags: python, datetime, discord, discord.py

So I'm trying to code a bot and part of it requires the "Last Seen" variable for when the user last logged onto the server (minecraft). I have an API that is set up to to detect when the user joins and post it in discord, but the issue is that when i translate the variable into `datetime`, it invariably gives me the time in UTC. Is there a way to translate the code into EST or another timezone?

The Code:

```
embed.add_field(name = "**Currently Playing**" , value = "Offline" , inline = True)
embed.add_field(name = "**Last Seen**" , value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(lastseen)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d at %H:%M %z %Z') , inline = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pytz` for your problem.

```
import pytz
timezone = pytz.timezone('<timezone>')  # Setting timezone
utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) # UTC
tz_now = utc_now.astimezone(timezone) # Converting to specified timezone
print(tz_now)
```

Comment: How would I put that into discord?